# Merge 2 class arrays and append according to date in a collection view

Tags: arrays, firebase, swift3, uicollectionview

Sorry this question has been asked before but I haven't managed to find a solution so I've reposted it to see if there is anyone else that could help me.

How can I merge 2 class arrays in a collection view? I have managed to display 2 arrays but how can I make them intertwine and append according to there postDate?

Below I have a photoPosts array and a videoPosts array and I am currently using the following method. But this only displays one array after another. Thanks in advance

```
var photoPosts = [photoPost]()
var videoPosts = [videoPost]()

func retrieveData(){
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("videoPost").child(uid)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dictionary = videoPost(snapshot: snapshot)
            self.videoPosts.append(dictionary)
             self.videoPosts.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
              return p1.postDate?.compare(p2.postDate!) == .orderedDescending
                })
 })
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("photoPost").child(uid)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dictionary = photoPost(snapshot: snapshot)
            self. photoPosts.append(dictionary)
                self.posts.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                    return p1.postDate?.compare(p2.postDate!) == .orderedDescending
                })
})
 self.newsfeedCollectionView?.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return videoPosts.count + photoPosts.count
}
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {         
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! newsfeedCollectionViewCell
             if indexPath.item < photoPosts.count {
                cell. photoPost = photoPosts[indexPath.item]
               } else {
                 cell.videoPost = videoPosts[indexPath.item-photoPosts.count]
                 }
                return cell
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below:

```
var combinedArray = NSMutableArray()

func retrieveData(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("videoPost").child(uid)
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let dictionary = videoPost(snapshot: snapshot)
        combinedArray.add(dictionary)
    })

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("photoPost").child(uid)
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let dictionary = photoPost(snapshot: snapshot)
        combinedArray.add(dictionary)
    })

    self.combinedArray.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
        var postDate1: Date?
        var postDate2: Date?
        if let photoPost1 = p1 as? photoPost {
            postDate1 = photoPost1.postDate
        } else if let videoPost1 = p1 as? videoPost {
            postDate1 = videoPost1.postDate
        }

        if let photoPost2 = p2 as? photoPost {
            postDate2 = photoPost2.postDate
        } else if let videoPost2 = p2 as? videoPost {
            postDate2 = videoPost2.postDate
        }

        return postDate1!.compare(postDate2!) == .orderedDescending
    })
    self.newsfeedCollectionView?.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return combinedArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! newsfeedCollectionViewCell

    if let photoItem = combinedArray[indexPath.item] as? photoPost {
        cell.photoPost = photoItem
    } else {
        cell.videoPost = combinedArray[indexPath.item] as videoPost
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there something else I can use in between `"[ ]"` because I get an error: Empty collection literal requires an explicit type for the line `var combinedArray = []`

Comment: I tried `var combinedArray = [] as NSArray` but I still get an error

Comment: Error: Empty collection literal requires an explicit type

Comment: Ok that fixed that problem but now I get an error:  Cannot convert value of type 'videoPost' to expected argument type '[Any]'. From the line `combinedArray.append(dictionary)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154819/discussion-between-vini-app-and-j-iese).